# Oracle Database schema validation

Tags: oracle-12c, migration, data-validation

I am working on a database migration and
want to validate the destination schema against the source schema for Tables, Views, Indexes, Sequences, Constraints etc. I can do that by querying the dba_ tables individually.
This is time consuming and we have to record the results manually
I was wondering if there is any pl/sql code which can be used to perform all these validations at once and give an output which can be stored in a CSV/excel

Comment: Use the "Database Diff" tool in Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Thanks @pmdba for the suggestion. I am aware of this tool, however I am trying to create a PL/SQL script to reduce the manual effort as well as getting an export of the counts to run a comparison. The database diff tool shows the differences and we can get the DDL for the objects which are not present in the destination database but we can't get an export of the differences